# Authenticating my Azure account opens a localhost webpage with invalid security

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I've been using Azure Storage Explorer for a few years without any problems. This morning I opened it and was told that I needed to reauthenticate, so I clicked the `Reauthenticate now` link.

This window opened...

[image]

At the same time a browser window opened with a URL which begins...

> https://localhost:61204/?code=

... and this is displayed...

[image]

Is there anything I can do about this? How else can I reauthenticate?

**UPDATE**
It seems that this problem goes further than I previously thought: I also cannot login to the Azure CLI or run any Powershell scripts which require authentication. In all cases I'm presented with a webpage showing `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

**UPDATE 2**
It looks like Firefox gives a bit more explanation of the problem:

[image]

Sure enough, if I change my default browser to Firefox then the process works.

Comment: Please open an issue for this on Storage Explorer GitHub repo. You’ll get a better response there IMHO. Here's the link: https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues.

Comment: Can you un-install and re-install the Storage Explorer: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/features/storage-explorer/ and try to reauthenticate and let me know the status 
Storage Explorer provides various ways to access your Azure Storage resources. Whatever method you choose, here are our recommendations. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-security#choosing-the-right-authentication-method

Comment: I've un- and re-installed; Same situation. I've removed and re-added the account, and it's still the same.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following worked for me (across VS, Storage Explorer and the Az Cli):

For Edge, go to `edge://net-internals/#hsts`

for Google Chrome, go to `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`

Under Delete domain security policies, fill in localhost and click Delete

from https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/10426

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have tried from my system.

Firstly, it goes to the https://login.microsoftonline.com

[image]

Post, it is reaching out to Localhost

[image]

We get a warning as it is insecure

[image]

Post that my account gets added

[image]

**Note:**

Storage explorer - Web browser Sign In Process : redirect to localhost is done at the end of the sign in process

Browser with warning, as redirect is being performed with HTTP instead of HTTPS and some browser force the redirect to be performed with HTTPS.

Feasible Options:

•   Ignore the warning.

•   Add an exception for localhost.

•   Disable force HTTPS, either globally or just for localhost.

Next Option: Changing where sign-in happens - Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-sign-in#changing-where-sign-in-happens

Browser complains about HTTP redirect during sign in Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-troubleshooting?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=Windows%2C2004#browser-complains-about-http-redirect-during-sign-in

Answer (score 1):

An easy workaround for me was to close azure store explorer, open visual studio, reauthenticate there, then open azure storage explorer again.

Answer (score 0):

Use below steps:

Step 1: open azure storage explorer

Step 2: open settings of azure storage explorer and click on services

[image: open settings of azure storage explorer and click on services]

Step 3: Check for Sign With option and change the default web browser to integrated Sign in and then try to sign in

[image: Check for Sign With option and change the default web browser to integrated Sign in and then try to sign in]

Answer (score 0):

Changing default browser to Edge from Chrome worked for me on Windows 11.

[image]